# Motion of an Object in a Viscous Fluid

Tags: fluid-dynamics, viscosity

Let us say that an object in a liquid is subject to a drag force proportional to its velocity -bv. What would be the graph of its vertical velocity as a function of time, taking into account the buoyant force as well?

Comment: If the velocity is zero then a straight line...

Comment: What are your thoughts on this so far?  Have you drawn a free body diagram?